# Installing ZendDebugger.so on OS X PHP 5.3.19

Tags: php, macos, zend-studio

I'm trying to get the ZendDebugger.so extension loaded in my custom (homebrew) PHP 5.3.19 install on OS X Mountain Lion, and all I get is:

```
Failed loading /path/to/php/extensions/ZendDebugger.so:  dlopen(/path/to/php/extensions/ZendDebugger.so, 9): Symbol not found: _executor_globals
  Referenced from: /path/to/php/extensions/ZendDebugger.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

That's what I get from php -m, php -v and the error_log.

It's not an architecture error, as I'm using 64 bit (and tried 32 on a lark) and I can't find anyone with this issue online. Is it just the PHP version? Some compilation flag missing? I can't figure it out.

Edit: ZendDebugger.so downloaded from: http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/downloads and using the 5.3.x version.

Comment: Just to be sure....  is /path/to/php/extensions/ or are you just pasting it exactly like it shows to you?

Comment: No, I obscured my path. It's actually using the php extensions directory where I have all my other extension files located.